# Find all the linked items to a particular item in an Object Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects. You'll be able to find a sample of complete data [here on JSONBlob.com](https://jsonblob.com/c6ee433d-b9d8-11eb-aa4d-db042e84b819).

Here's a simplified preview:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Unbetitelt",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [{
      "i": "60a64930cf1db1710b97bf7a",
    }],
    "id": "60a6472ecf1db1710b97bf4c"
  },
  {
    "name": "middleparent",
    "parentCubo": "60a6472ecf1db1710b97bf4c",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [{
        "i": "60a64936cf1db1710b97bf7d",
      },
      {
        "i": "60a649afcf1db1710b97bfa6",
      }
    ],
    "id": "60a64930cf1db1710b97bf7a"
  },
  {
    "name": "Unbetitelt",
    "parentCubo": "60a64930cf1db1710b97bf7a",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [
      {
        "i": "60a6494acf1db1710b97bf8f",
      },
      {
        "i": "60a64976cf1db1710b97bf9a",
      }
    ],
    "id": "60a64936cf1db1710b97bf7d"
  },
  {
    "name": "Unbetitelt",
    "parentCubo": "60a64930cf1db1710b97bf7a",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [],
    "id": "60a649afcf1db1710b97bfa6"
  },
  {
    "name": "Unbetitelt",
    "parentCubo": "60a649c5cf1db1710b97bfb1",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [],
    "id": "60a649efcf1db1710b97bfc4"
  }
]
```

Each object in this array(the root array) has an `id` and `childrenLayout` property.

The `childrenLayout` property is an array(the child array) of Objects which will have an `i` property but won't have another `childrenLayout`. So in order to find children of each item in the `childrenLayout` array, we'll have to use this `i` field and find objects in the root array.

Once we find those objects in the root array, if the `childrenLayout` property on those objects is not an empty array, then we have to repeat the same process and find objects in this object's `childrenLayout`, thereby creating a list of all ids that are linked to one specific object with `id` x.

So, for instance, if we try to find all the items linked with `id` `60a6472ecf1db1710b97bf4c`, we'll get:

- `60a64930cf1db1710b97bf7a`
- `60a64936cf1db1710b97bf7d`
- `60a649afcf1db1710b97bfa6`
- `60a6494acf1db1710b97bf8f`
- `60a64976cf1db1710b97bf9a`

This is what I have so far and it's obviously not working as expcted and only returns the last three items from the expected items list mentioned above:

```
const findChildFor = item => {
  if (item.childrenLayout.length > 0) {
    const detailsOfItems = item.childrenLayout.map(({ i }) =>
      data.find(datum => datum.id === i)
    );
    return detailsOfItems.map(itemDetails => findChildFor(itemDetails));
  } else {
    return item.id;
  }
};
const [firstItem] = data;
// TODO: Work on a way to make it return children without having to flatten it.
const childrenRelatedToFirstItem = findChildFor(firstItem);
console.log(
  'childrenRelatedToFirstItem: ',
  childrenRelatedToFirstItem.flat(10)
);
```

To help speed up the solution, **[here's a Sample Stackblitz with the code so far](https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-find-items-linked-to-an-item-in-an-array?file=index.js)**.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: sorry but I dont really understand what you want to achieve? do you want to find all object in the array with a specific childrenLayout i? could you give an example how the return object should look like if it worked

Comment: Totally it's a bit tricky to understand. So considering there's an array, I want to find all the objects linked with a particular object in that array. I've also given an example above if that helps. My logic doesn't seem to work as expected, unfortunately. Could you please check the sample stackblitz I've linked at the end of the question? That has the code I've written so far.

Comment: or you want the first array of every childLayout?

Comment: Maybe not just filter. That would have been wayyy too easy. Each object in the array(the root array) has a `childrenLayout` property which is an array in itself. Each object in the `childrenLayout` would have an `i` property that belongs to an object in the root array.

I want to write a function that could give traverse the whole root array a couple of times and find all items that are somehow present in the `childrenLayout` property of the root object or the object linked to the `i` property on the `childrenLayout` property

Comment: aaaaah i see now

Comment: Extremely sorry if it's too hard to understand, coz it is indeed a pretty complex logic. If you go through the sample data above and then check out the expected list of items that I've mentioned in the question, it might probably help.

Comment: I believe I've cracked it.  I didn't really notice I was getting duplicate values. But I think it's fixed now with `[...new Set(linkedChildren)]` Gonna update this thread with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Code isn't so complex. Hoping this would be helpful.

```
const findChildFor = (arr, id, output) => {
    const item = arr.find(obj => obj.id === id);
    if (item) {
        const childs = item.childrenLayout;
        for (let child of childs) {
            output.push(child.i);
            findChildFor(arr, child.i, output);
        }
    }
}

output = [];
findChildFor(data, '60a6472ecf1db1710b97bf4c', output);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This data looks like a graph description. Here is my solution for the problem with optimized time complexity and taking care of cyclic connections.

```
const findAllChildren = (arr, id) => {
  // to find each child with O(1) access time
  const familyMap = new Map(arr.map(it => [it.id, it.childrenLayout]));
  // to check if a child has been collected with O(1) access time   
  const resultSet = new Set();
  const findChildrenFor = (parentId) => {
    familyMap.get(parentId).forEach(({i}) => {
      // in a case of a cyclic graph
      if (!resultSet.has(i)) {
        resultSet.add(i);
        findChildrenFor(i);
      }
    });
  };
  return Array.from(findChildrenFor(id));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I through in a solution in a different way but with the result that you want.

```
dataArray.reduce((acc,cur)=>{
    acc[cur.id] = [];
    cur.childrenLayout.map(child=>acc[cur.id].push(child.i))
    Object.entries(acc).map(obj=>{
       if(obj[1].includes(cur.id)){
          cur.childrenLayout.map(child=>acc[obj[0]].push(child.i))
       }
    })
   return acc;
},{})
```

Any question leave it in the comments section.

```js
const dataArray = [
  {
    "name": "Unbetitelt",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [{
      "i": "60a64930cf1db1710b97bf7a",
    }],
    "id": "60a6472ecf1db1710b97bf4c"
  },
  {
    "name": "middleparent",
    "parentCubo": "60a6472ecf1db1710b97bf4c",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [{
        "i": "60a64936cf1db1710b97bf7d",
      },
      {
        "i": "60a649afcf1db1710b97bfa6",
      }
    ],
    "id": "60a64930cf1db1710b97bf7a"
  },
  {
    "name": "Unbetitelt",
    "parentCubo": "60a64930cf1db1710b97bf7a",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [
      {
        "i": "60a6494acf1db1710b97bf8f",
      },
      {
        "i": "60a64976cf1db1710b97bf9a",
      }
    ],
    "id": "60a64936cf1db1710b97bf7d"
  },
  {
    "name": "Unbetitelt",
    "parentCubo": "60a64930cf1db1710b97bf7a",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [],
    "id": "60a649afcf1db1710b97bfa6"
  },
  {
    "name": "Unbetitelt",
    "parentCubo": "60a649c5cf1db1710b97bfb1",
    "organizationMap": "60a55ed4e3a8973a02f910f1",
    "childrenLayout": [],
    "id": "60a649efcf1db1710b97bfc4"
  }
]

const childFinder = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((acc,cur)=>{
    acc[cur.id] = [];
cur.childrenLayout.map(child=>acc[cur.id].push(child.i))
Object.entries(acc).map(obj=>{
    if(obj[1].includes(cur.id)){
cur.childrenLayout.map(child=>acc[obj[0]].push(child.i))
    }
})
return acc;
},{})
}

console.log(childFinder(dataArray))
```